# Putting 2 millions objects in Hazelcast cluster of 5 nodes - what optimization we should do

Tags: hazelcast, vert.x, hazelcast-imap

We have 2 millions objects coming from REST API in chunks of 500 objects in each API call (apprx 750 MB of data in total).

- When we put these objects in Hazelcast cache as following then it takes around **10 minutes – CPU is 5-6%** - this makes sense because there are 2 million blocking n/w calls.

  ```
  vertx.executeBlocking {
      for(2 million times) {
          hazelcast.put(mapName, key, value)
      }
  }
  ```
- When we don’t use vertx’s “executeblocking” and rather do as following then whole process finish in **10-15 seconds but CPU reaches 80%**. I am using Hazelcast mancenter, so I could see that all 2 millions objects are reflected in cache within 10-15 seconds.

  ```
  for(2 million times) {
      hazelcast.putAsync(mapName, key, value)
  }
  ```
- When we used **#putAll** as following then **CPU reaches 60%**, which is **better than second approach**. This approach also finishes in apprx 10 seconds.

  ```
  for(2 million objects in chunks of 500) {
      hazelcast.putAll(mapName, collection-of-500-objects)
  }
  ```

Any optimization that you guys recommend? I wonder why Hazelcast is spiking the CPU so much.

FYI - Think **vertx.executeBlocking** as executing a piece of code asynchronously. We are using Intel Xeon 8 Core CPU with 12GB RAM.

Comment: Sorry for bad formatting, I couldn't figure it out to format the code.

Comment: `vertx.executeBlocking` is technically not running asynchronously, rather it allow *synchronous* code to be executed safely within vert.x, returning the results to the asynchronous code (running in a verticle) when done.

Comment: PS formatting code in bullets requires 4 extra spaces. I edited it

Comment: @Arnold Schrijver - I meant to simplify it. Vertx execute the lambda using a worker thread from pool, and you can attach the result handlers, which will be invoked when worker thread is done with the execution. I am not trying to justifying my statement, but at the same time I want to make sure I articulate it correctly. So I still think it's executing the code asyncronously with vertx's. Feel free to correct me if I am still wrong. I appreciate your time to format my code!!!

Comment: No you were not wrong, I was just clarifying. Both methods may be valid depending on your needs. The second approach still blocks the event loop for 10-15sec, not using vert.x power. Maybe you could wrap that in executeBlocking or worker verticle, or have regular verticles do individual puts. Feels a bit strange. I don't know if you will gain much, as you are only doing single hazelcast operation. But blocking the event loop longer than needed is the worst sin in vert.x :)

Comment: @ArnoldSchrijver - I agree that event-loop will be blocked for 10-15 sec in second approach but that I am doing just for testing purpose. My main focus is why CPU goes 80% when I use hazelcast.putAsync

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at IMap.putAll. It allows putting data in chunks. You said 2mln divided by 500 objects a chunk = 4k chunks

```
/**
 * {@inheritDoc}
 * <p>
 *      No atomicity guarantees are given. It could be that in case of failure
 *      some of the key/value-pairs get written, while others are not.
 * </p>
 * <p>
 *      <p><b>Warning:</b></p>
 *      If you have previously set a TTL for the key, the TTL remains unchanged and the entry will
 *      expire when the initial TTL has elapsed.
 * </p>
 */
void putAll(Map<? extends K, ? extends V> m);
```

Comment: Atomicity is important for us. This method seems to not provide any atomicity guarantee. We wouldn't know if some of our data is lost. Also, I am wondering if it will have a same effect on CPU usage as #putAsync did (caused CPU to spike 80%).

Comment: I ran test with hazelcast.putAll(collection) and it showed some improvement on CPU (60%) v/s putting object one-by-one in cache using hazelcast.put(key, value) where CPU is 80%. Anything under 40% would have been acceptable to me. BTW, we are using 8 Core Intel Xeon CPU.

Answer (score 0):

> Any optimization that you guys recommend?

You can try to use [IMap.setAsync](http://docs.hazelcast.org/docs/latest/javadoc/com/hazelcast/core/IMap.html#setAsync-K-V-) instead of IMap.putAsync, according to documentation it should be more efficient:

> Similar to the put operation except that set doesn't return the old value, which is more efficient.

Comment: Hazelcast version(3.6.2) used by us doesn't have this method. We will upgrade the version and see how it works.